# USB communication between Android phone and MCU while continuously charging the phone

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, charging, usb-c, usb-host

I am working on a project where I have to communicate between an Android phone and a microcontroller through USB and continuously charge the phone. I have very limited experience with USB and would like some advice in my PCB design process.

The Android device has a type USB-C connector and is using USB 2.0 specification. The device will charge passively the vast majority of the time and I have no critical time constraints so the most simple solution that is robust is my goal.

My questions/considerations are the following:

I have been considering using STM32F446xC/E, the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f446re.pdf) (page 36) says "For OTG/Host modes, a power switch is needed in case bus-powered devices are connected"
Is it possible to use a usb-c to micro usb-b cable and design the pcb/mcu as a host like the application note from the same datasheet?
[image]

Alternatively, if there is a problem with the solution that I do not realize, do I have to design it according to the dual mode like this ?

[image]

I have not started the design yet so I am flexible in my solution, if you have any other suggestion I would very much like to hear them!

Answer (score 1):

If you want your MCU communicating with your android phone, the most common approach will be to use the MCU in a **Device** mode. Otherwise your phone (as a **Device** connected to a **Host** – a PC or MCU) will typically act as a storage device or a camera, you choose it on your phone when it is attached to a Host.

MCU's **Device** mode, on the other hand, is the same as connecting your MCU to a computer (via virtual COM-port over USB) like arduino does. You can communicate with your phone the same way, if the phone has USB OTG support. Which most of modern android phones does (check the phone specifications). If it doesn't, consider using bluetooth.
If it does, all you need is a simple OTG Y cable like this one (except a USB-C version):
[image: USB OTG Y Cable]
[Here is a video example.](https://youtu.be/2cOH_vCA6HA)

It does exactly what you need: charging your phone while phone is communicating with an external USB device.
It's also a good idea to make sure your phone (even if it does support USB OTG) is working with your MCU correctly – OS version, driver compatibility, etc. A dev board is handy for prototyping. You can test it with an Android app like **Serial USB Terminal**.

In any case, if you want to permanently attach your phone to a charger for a long period of time (to act as a touch screen of sort), you should consider powering your phone directly with [3.3V - 4.2V] from a **filtered** and **stabilised** buck converter or even a linear regulator, thus replacing the battery away. Because a lithium cell will degrade in this mode fast. About 3 to 12 month, depending on its quality (if new).
Degraded lithium battery (esp. left unattended) could swell, overheat, explode, damage your phone and even cause fire.

Comment: Be very very careful with USB Y-cables as far too many on the market violated the specification in dangerous ways.  The cable in the photo provided appears to have a micro-B plug on one end, this is a violation of the specification.  There's a comment on this on the USB hardware Wikipedia page:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#Accessory_charging_adaptors_(ACA)  By getting that one detail wrong there's a high probability that there's other things wrong, potentially hardware damaging things.

Answer (score 1):

A USB-C to micro-B cable wired to the USB spec would not be wired in a way to indicate to what is on the micro-B end to become host/master/"A-mode", it would be wired for guest/slave/"B-mode", and how it works and why gets complex fast.  Before I go further I need to define my terms.  It is unfortunate that the word "device" is overloaded so I'll use a convention I saw in other documents and use "A-mode" and "B-mode" to describe the two states for micro-AB ports.

Wiring a micro-B port to stay in A-mode means it is supplying power all the time.  If it is not supplying power then many B-mode devices won't work when connected, the presence of power starts the communication even for devices that don't require USB for power.  I've seen "hacks" to make this work but that means using cables or devices wired in nonstandard ways.  It appears the intent is to use off the shelf cables and devices so wiring a micro-B port to stay in A-mode undesirable and potentially hazardous to hardware.

You would not have to wire the port for dual mode, it could be wired to stay in B-mode.  If the MCU supports dual mode then it supports going into B-mode only, just "pretend" an adapter is permanently attached.  The wiring for this might not be documented explicitly but it should be fairly trivial to figure out.

One reason why I don't like the word "device" when USB is in the room is because with word "device" overloaded the part "device will charge passively" is confusing.  Which end of the cable do you want charging?  The micro-B end or the type-C end?  Power out of a B-mode only port breaks the USB spec.  If the type-C end is providing power to the micro-B end then that does not appear to be much of a problem, so long as the required power is not too high.

USB-OTG allows for power to flow in opposition to the original definition of A-mode and B-mode using the "accessory charging adapter" part of the spec.  USB-C and USB-OTG don't always get along and as I recall this is one part where they don't get along too well.  I would expect that there is a means to make this work, it just doesn't appear trivial to me.  I could be missing something important but if you want A-mode and power flowing in with USB-C in the loop then that's complicated.  Or at least it appears complicated, an accessory charging adapter may actually be quite simple but I don't know much about it.